# How avoid Pygame crashing a new mac pro with spinning ball

Tags: python-3.x, crash

I have worked with python 3 for a few months. Just a few days ago I have installed pygame and have been doing early tutorials. In two separate situations when I run a python script, the mac halts with a spinning ball and I need to cmd-opt-esc to abort it. I have done googling and not found similar complaints. As one example, I'm running the Chimp game and it loads a chimp image in a new little window, then spinning ball. Restarting the mac didn't help. Sound familiar, and/or does anyone here have guidance?

Answer (score 0):

Found out the problem:
-- The basic issue was a simple one. The chimp program tries to locate its support files (two images and two sounds) in a *subdirectory* called /data. 
-- It was attempting to load a file using that path, and of course had a failure.
-- So I got it working OK after fixing that.
-- The only question that remains is why the python/idle processes totally crash with a spinning ball when the script encounters a missing file error!

Thanks 
Eric